# Почему не стоит запихивать хендлеры внутрь других хендлеров

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, telebot

Почему нельзя делать так?

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands=['weather'])
async def weather_handler(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Введи название города...')

    @dp.message_handler()
    async def get_city_name(message: types.Message):
        # обработка введённых данных от юзера
        pass
```

PS. Табуляция верна.
PS_2. Сделал вопрос чтобы на него ссылаться в будущем.

Comment: А как это вообще в питоне логически работает, как можно функцию определить внутри другой функции?

Comment: @mazik7512 [ссылка](https://www.bestprog.net/ru/2020/08/12/python-nested-functions-nested-scopes-name-search-rules-in-case-of-nested-functions-factory-functions-passing-values-to-a-nested-function-ru/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ в большинстве своем подходит как для `aiogram` так и для `pytelegrambotapi`.

Для начала опишу примерный ход действий бота при получении сообщения.

1. Вы запускаете бота.
2. Он проходит по всему видимому коду, и записывает(видимые) хендлеры в свой внутренний список.
3. Юзер отправляет команду `/weather`
4. Бот проходит по списку хендлеров, и начинает сверяться с фильтрами внутри хендлеров, по типу `content_types=[...]`, `regex="..."`, ну или некую лябмюду `func=lambda msg: msg.text=='...'`
5. Натыкается на `commands=['weather']` и тригерит функцию `weather_handler`
6. И тут начинается хрень. Программа проходит по коду `weather_handler` и видит еще один хендлер, который не имеет фильтра (по факту будет иметь `content_types=['text']` и `state=None`(Aiogram)), и само собой записывает его в свой список хендлеров (смотри пункт 2).
7. Дальше юзер вводит текст, который с большей долей вероятности попадает в `get_city_name` и вроде бы код даже работает как надо, и в целом можно забить на эту тему, при условии что ваш бот имеет только одну такую шляпу.
   Проблемы возникают когда появляется еще одна функция без фильтров.

К примеру такой код:

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands=['weather'])
async def weather_handler(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Введи название города...')

    @dp.message_handler()
    async def get_city_name(message: types.Message):
        # обработка введённых данных от юзера
        pass

@dp.message_handler()
async def get_all_text(message: types.Message):
    pass
```

Будет всё ломать. Функция `get_city_name` никогда не сработает, так как в список хендлеров попадет позже чем `get_all_text` и вы будете грустить, что не продумали это заранее.

Итак, как это исправить, чтобы это работало наверняка?

## pytelegrambotapi

Для `pytelegrambotapi` нужно юзать `register_next_step_handler`.

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['weather'])
def weather_handler(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Введи название города...')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_city_name)


def get_city_name(message: types.Message):
    # обработка введённых данных от юзера
    pass


@bot.message_handler()
def get_all_text(message: types.Message):
    pass
```

Логика работы следующая:
в `register_next_step_handler` пихаете первым аргументом объект `Message` который в целом можно брать текущий без создания нового по типу

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['weather'])
def weather_handler(message: types.Message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Введи название города...')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, get_city_name)
```

Видел как так делают, но особого смысла нет. Разве что вы пересылаете месседж в какой-то другой чат, то тогда стоит делать именно так.
А другим аргументом название функции, которая должна сработать. Само собой в той функции должен быть обязательный аргумент `message: types.Message` иначе будет ошибка.
Также вы можете передавать аргументы в следующую функцию. К примеру так.

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['weather'])
def weather_handler(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Введи название города...')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_city_name)


def get_city_name(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введи что-то еще")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_extra_data, message.text)


def get_extra_data(message: types.Message, city_name: str):
    print(city_name, message.text)
```

Тут мы в еще одну функцию передаем то что юзер написал в текущей(название города), а в следующей можно получить еще какие-то данные и обработать всё как вам нужно.
Ну и напоследок скажу, что аргументов так можно передать сколько вы хотите, просто добавляйте их через запятую.

## Возможные проблемы

Ну во первых нельзя красиво сделать так чтобы прервать этот `register_next_step_handler`.
То есть если вы вдруг захотите во время получения названия города прекратить это, то вам придется либо дойти до конца цепочки, либо в каждой такой функции писать что-то типа

```
def get_city_name(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == "/cancel":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы прервали ввод")
        return

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введи что-то еще")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_extra_data, message.text)
```

Что выглядит довольно убого.

## Aiogram

Для `aiogram` стоит использовать `state`. Пример.

```py
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State

bot = Bot(token="token")
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())

class WeatherStates(StatesGroup):
    get_city_name = State()
    get_extra_data = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['weather'])
async def weather_handler(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Введите название города...')
    await WeatherStates.get_city_name.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=WeatherStates.get_city_name)
async def get_city_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Введите что-то еще...')
    await WeatherStates.next()
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['city_name'] = message.text


@dp.message_handler(state=WeatherStates.get_extra_data)
async def get_extra_data(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        print(data['city_name'], message.text)
    await state.finish()
```

Выглядит длиннее, но могу уверять что значительно надёжнее. Что мы тут делаем, импортируем нужные модули, и после делаем диспатчер с аргументом `storage=MemoryStorage()` нужно для того чтобы боту было где хранить данные стейтов и просто нужные данные.
Дальше делаем класс для стейтов.
После мы вместо `register_next_step_handler` пишем `await WeatherStates.get_city_name.set()` как-бы запускаем конкретное состояние для определённого юзера(а еще для определенного чата).
После юзер пишет название города и попадает в `get_city_name` где мы сразу меняем стейт `await WeatherStates.next()` на следующий в группе `WeatherStates` и записываем то что написал юзер в словарь.

```py
async with state.proxy() as data:
    data['city_name'] = message.text
```

Примерная схема хранения такая:

```
память_стейта = {
    "какой-то_чат_айди": {
        "какой-то_юзер_айди": {
            "state": "",
            "data": {}# тут хранятся данные 
        }
    }
}
```

Ну а потом юзер снова что-то пишет мы попадаем в `get_extra_data` и снова заходим в хранилище и оперируем данными, как мы хотим.
И напоследок `await state.finish()` сбрасывает текущий стейт, и все данные в хранилище для `чата->юзера`.
Ну это нужно делать тогда когда вам точно не нужны данные в хранилище стейта, и сам стейт. Можно конечно сбросить только данные так `await state.reset_data()` или только стейт `await state.reset_state(with_data=False)`