# aiogarm после команды должен принимать ответ от пользователя

Tags: python, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["member"], content_types=["text"])
async def do_something(message: types.Message):
    message.reply(('Отправьте ник Пользователя') , parse_mode="html" )
```

`membertext = message.text`

Команду /member принимает как ответ от пользователя
Нужно сделать так чтобы команды он не принимал только принимал тексты

Comment: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html

Comment: глянь в конце я описал как юзать FSM https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1478675/Почему-не-стоит-запихивать-хендлеры-внутрь-других-хендлеров/1478676#1478676