# Можно в Aiogram в FSM реализовать вызов состояния, не попрядку?

Tags: python, aiogram

в документации примера не нашел. в видео на youtube, примеры однотипные.

```
class Math_task(StatesGroup):
        Math_task1=State()
        Math_task2=State()
        Math_task3=State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['Choice_level'],state='*')
async def Choice_level_cmd(message:types.Message,state: FSMContext):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,text='Выберите уровень',
                            parse_mode="HTML",
                           reply_markup=lkb)

    await Math_task.next()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['math_task1'],state=Math_task.Math_task1)
async def math_task1(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    a = random.randrange(0, 100)
    b = random.randrange(0, 100)
    c=a+b
    await message.answer(text=f'Найти сумму {a}, {b}',reply_markup=back_keyboard)
    # await message.answer(reply_markup=back_keyboard)

    print(c)
    for q in range(3):
        @dp.message_handler(state=Math_task.Math_task1)
        async def math_task1_2(message: types.Message,state: FSMContext):
            if  str(message.text) == str(c):
                await message.answer("Правильно")
                a = random.randrange(0, 100)
                b = random.randrange(0, 100)
                await message.answer(text=f'Найти сумму {a}, {b}')
                print(c)
            if  str(message.text) != str(c) and str(message.text)!='/BACK' and 
                str(message.text) not in alllevel and str(message.text)!='/start':
                await message.answer('Неправильно, пробуй еще.')
                a = random.randrange(0, 100)
                b = random.randrange(0, 100)
                print(c)
                await message.answer(text=f'Найти сумму {a}, {b}')
            if  str(message.text)=='/start':
                await state.finish()
            if  str(message.text)=='/BACK':
                await state.finish()
```

для math_task2 такой практически код, но найти разность, для math_task3 найти произведение.

что нужно прописать вместо `await Math_task.next()`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему не стоит запихивать хендлеры внутрь других хендлеров](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1478675/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%85%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%85%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%85%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2)

Answer (score 0):

Вызов стейтов не по порядку реализуется
Ручным вызовом стэйта `await state_name.set()`