# Отправка сообщений TG-ботом при нажатии кнопки python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Пишу тг бота, который даёт промокоды на всякие сервисы. Основная проблема заключается в том, что при нажатии на inline button бот не отвечает сообщением. То есть надо, чтобы если пользователь нажмёт на одну из кнопок, то бот ему ответит сообщением. Я ещё совсем зеленый в пайтоне да и в коде, в целом, поэтому буду рад быстрой помощи)

```
введите сюда код

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(m, res=False):
    bot.send_message(m.chat.id, 'Я на связи. Напиши мне что-нибудь )')
# Получение сообщений от юзера
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='button', callback_data='bt1')
    button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='button', callback_data='btn2')
    button3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='button', callback_data='btn3')
    button4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='button', callback_data='btn4')
    markup.add(button1, button2, button3, button4)

    if message.text == "Хочу подписку":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, reply_markup=markup, text="Вот все доступные подписки на данный момент")

    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: callback.data)
    def check_callback_data(callback):
        if callback.data == "btn1":
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Ваш код...', reply_markup=markup)

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)`
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему не стоит запихивать хендлеры внутрь других хендлеров](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1478675/Почему-не-стоит-запихивать-хендлеры-внутрь-других-хендлеров)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы бот отвечал сообщением на нажатую Вами инлайн-кнопку необходимо создать callback_query_handler, который будет принимать значение callback_data в качестве аргумента:

```
    #создаём инлайн-кнопку
    hello_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    btn_1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Привет', callback_data='hello')
    hello_markup.insert(btn_1)

    #реагирует на callback_data, которую мы ввели в инлайн-кнопку выше
    @dp.callback_query_handler(text ="hello") 
    async def hello(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
        await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, 'И тебе привет!')
```